# MLM for between subjects exposure to same stimulus

Tags: r, regression, multilevel-analysis

Lets say I have a dataset from an experiment, which looks like:

```
   id    image   fd   rt
0   1  111.jpg  1.1  377
1   1  213.jpg  1.5  463
2   1  142.jpg  1.8  195
3   2  111.jpg  1.1  380
4   2  213.jpg  1.5  208
5   2  142.jpg  1.8  335
6   3  111.jpg  1.1  199
7   3  213.jpg  1.5  353
8   3  142.jpg  1.8  468
```

Each person (`id`) sees a set of images (`image`) and we record their response time to each image (`rt`). From each image we also calculate some statistic (fractal dimension in this case, `fd`), and the value will always be the same for a given image

Using R, I want to determine whether there is a relationship between the statistic `fd` and an individuals response time to that image. The research question is essentially "are peoples responses faster/slower when viewing images that are higher/lower on fractal dimension?"

I believe this calls for a multilevel model, as `rt` is likely to be clustered by `id`, so I have tried the following model:

```
rt ~ 1 + fd + (1 + fd | id)
```

However, I'm not sure that this captures all of the clustering that exists in the data. `fd` is always the same for a given image, so you'll notice that there are only 3 unique `fd` values (for 3 unique images)

Does the fact that `fd` values are repeated need to be addressed? and if so, what would be the correct model for this? Or does it not matter given that `fd` repeats only exist between subjects?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no great expert at this, but wouldn't this

```
rt ~ 1 + 1|fd + 1|id
```

do the trick?

Comment: I guess I'm trying to understand at a more conceptual level *why* that might be needed, or why my existing model is ok as-is (given the repeats are only between-subjects)